# Set some default guid value in uniqueidentifier in sql

Tags: sql, default, default-value, unique-constraint

I need to set default guid value, not `NEWID()` in uniqueidentifier column in SQL.

For example: Have a column TestID in TestTable, need to set default TestID to `"DA74F684-B228-48D5-9692-69465BE6D720"`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your script.

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable drop COLUMN TestID 

ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD TestID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT cast('DA74F684-B228-48D5-9692-69465BE6D720' as uniqueidentifier);
```

then, update exsting records

```
UPDATE TestTable  set TestID = 'DA74F684-B228-48D5-9692-69465BE6D720'
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But it is still setting NULL value for all the existing records.

TestSaranshId1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: Ok .. Thank you a lot.